# Applying float property to checkbox then unable to click on ckeckbox?

Tags: html, css, css-float

To achieve this [image] ihave made the following code

```css
.ContentList {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(148,135,148,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(148,135,148,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(148,135,148,1);
}

    .ContentList .ItemCells {
        width: 270px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: solid 1px;
    }

    .ContentList .ItemCellsTitle {
        width: inherit;
        height: 50px;
        border: solid 1px orange;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

.ItemCellsTitle h4 {
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    left: 5px;
}

.ItemCellsContent {
    border: solid 1px green;
    height: 65%;
}

/*.SelectionIndicator {
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
}*/

input[type="checkbox"] {
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ContentList">
        <asp:DataList ID="dlContentList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <div class="ItemCells">
                    <div class="ItemCellsContent">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ContentCD") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ItemCellsTitle">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbContentID" runat="server" />
                 
                        <h4>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ContentTitle") %></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
```

This posed a new problem that i was unable to click on checkbox anymore.If i hover mouse on it i'm not getting any focus on checkbox(default behavior) .But if i remove float property of checkbox  then it is working fine and i'm able select and unselect it.Why i was unable to click on checkbox when i apply float property

For your reference after removing float property
[image]

Thanks .....

Answer (score 1):

Remove the float and don't wrap your text in H4.  Instead, style the ItemCellsTitle class to mimic the H4 style you are looking for - or, you can change the CSS for your H4 and set display to inline.  Either one will work if you remove the float.